# Is share point working for php

Tags: php, sharepoint

is it possible to working with share point with php?

I want to keep a application developed in php on share point is it possible ?

Regards
Prabhakar

Comment: What do you mean by "working with share point with php"? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Are you trying to use SharePoint as an SVN / GIT / Mercurial alternative? If so, I have never tried it, but as long as you can store text on it, sure why not? I would prefer the SVN / GIT route though.

Comment: Share point is a collab suite. SVN/git/mercurial are version control systems. How are they related?

Comment: I guess my statement is a bit misleading. Basically I was just trying to see if that was the functionality he was looking to replace. But as stated, they are not related. I was just going off of him stating "application developed in php" as he wants to use it like sed systems. But of course, SharePoint would not be an ideal system to develop under, given that it does not have a version-able system.

Comment: Maybe the author just wants to query SharePoint data? The question is too foggy.

Answer (score 1):

PHP apps require a PHP runtime to work. Sharepoint doesn't include a PHP runtime. You can, however, deploy PHP and Sharepoint to IIS. Sharepoint doesn't host PHP, though; IIS does. Check out [this page](http://php.iis.net/) for more information on running PHP in IIS.